# Holomorphic maps of complex manifolds preserve the bidegree of a complex differential form

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

For a holomorphic map $f : M \to N$ between complex manifolds show that if $\omega$ is a form of type $(p,q)$ on $N$, then $f^*\omega$ is a form of type $(p,q)$ on $M$.

---

I am wondering if the following is enough to establish this. Let $\omega$ be form of type $(p,q)$. Locally $$\omega = \sum_{I,J} \omega_{I,J} dz_I \wedge d\bar{z}_J.$$ We have the following: $$f^*\omega = \sum_{I,J} \omega_{I,J} \circ f d(z_I \circ f) \wedge d(\bar{z}_J \circ f)$$

and $d(z_I \circ f)$ is a $(p,0)$ form and $d(\bar{z}_J \circ f)$ a $(0,q)$ form so the wedge is a $(p,q)$ form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pullbacks respect order of forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697922/pullbacks-respect-order-of-forms)

Comment: The second answer seems to have something similar to what I considered here, but I don't know if they are concluding this just from that? The answer you have provided looks like it has almost complex structures on the manifolds and only considers forms of type $(1,0)$. @QuaereVerum

Comment: It suffices to prove the $(1,0)$ case, by locally decomposing arbitrary forms. Furthermore, any complex structure has an associated almost complex structure, which is how the type of a differential form is usually definen, to begin with.